# Class name conflict across modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm running into an issue in a Rails 4 application related to class names and modules.

I have an `Event` class in my main application that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. I also have a set of files in my /lib directory that have been grouped into a module I call `LibModule`. There's a class in that module that's also named `Event`. I noticed something interesting about referencing these classes. Here are some examples using the Rails console.

Example #1: When Event has never been referenced, the ActiveRecord version gets loaded:

```
> Event
=> Event(id: integer...)
```

Example #2: When LibModule::Event gets referenced first:

```
> LibModule::Event
=> LibModule::Event
> Event
=> LibModule::Event
```

As a result, when my server restarts (after updates, etc), I'll occasionally get the following error if a user engages in behavior that triggers server activity similar to Example #2:

```
superclass mismatch for class Event
```

I know there are a few ways to ensure that there's no conflict here. What's the best practice way of handling a situation like this?

1. I tried replicating the behavior from Example #2 with class names from gems and it seems like Rails completely segregates the classes in gems. Is there a way to do the same here? I think this would be my ideal situation.
2. Should I just change the name of `LibModule::Event`?
3. Should I ensure that the `ActiveRecord` class loads during initialization?
4. Some other Rails best practice I haven't thought of?

Comment: This is a non-trivial and somewhat unintuitive area. [I highly recommend reading this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with [the way qualified constants are resolved by the Rails autoloader](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-algorithms-qualified-references). The documentation offers the following solution:

> Naming conflicts of this kind are rare in practice, but if one occurs, `require_dependency` provides a solution by ensuring that the constant needed to trigger the heuristic is defined in the conflicting place.

The solution, in your case, is to add this just above the class definition for `LibModule::Event`:

```
require_dependency 'event'
```

This will inform the autoloader of the `::Event` constant that references your ActiveRecord model, ensuring the appropriate constant naming for `LibModule::Event`.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's nothing in Ruby that precludes you from having duplicated class names, the Rails auto-loader does get easily confused by them which can cause a lot of problems.

Typically I go out of my way to avoid duplication for this very reason. Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't, and the working/not-working aspect of the code can often depend on which entry point is taken, which things are loaded first, making it unpredictable.

You can try and circumvent this by force-loading your `Event` class using `require_relative` at the end of `lib_module.rb`.

Comment: Note: The docs specifically say *not* to do what you're suggesting: [“Files defining constants to be autoloaded should never be required”](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-require)

Answer (score 0):

to reference the main event class try `::Event`. `::` is a scope resolution operator, which specifies the global/main scope.